# How to choose nonzero $B$ such that $AB = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on a problem and have used enough theorems to the point that I have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ which *has a zero row in its last row*. I am looking for a nonzero matrix $B$ which is such that $AB = 0$. Can anyone give me a hint for how to choose $B$?

Comment: Could you do this if $B$ was an $n \times 1$ column vector instead? That is, could you find a non-zero column vector $x$ such that $Ax = 0$?

Comment: $A$ of this form shows that $\ker(A)$ is at least one-dimensional, say $0\ne v\in\ker(A)$. All you have to do is to find a non-zero matrix $B$ such that its image is $\mathrm{span}(v)$. This should be doable (take $v$ as your first basis vector, and extend this to a basis of your whole vector space; then map everything to $v$).

Comment: @Gargantuar I am at a point in Hoffman and Kunze at which these notions haven't been introduced, so I'm trying to do it explicitly just in terms of matrix theory.

Comment: Let $B$ be a matrix of all zeros and a single $1$. Can you figure out where to place the $1$ such that your property is true?

Comment: @TheoBendit I'm not sure, because the last column of $A$ is what gives me trouble. Would it be possible to give one further hint?

Comment: If I put it in the $B_{nn}$ entry then I have $(AB)_{in} \neq 0$ for arbitrary $i$. Only for $(AB)_{nn}$ does the fact that $A_{nn} = 0$ help me. I'm still not sure I can see it unfortunately. @whpowell96

Comment: @EE18 It wasn't really intended as a hint so much as it was gauging what you're familiar with. I was essentially going to say what Gargantuar did: if you find such a non-zero $x$, you can put it in all the columns. Finding such an $x$ should just be the usual Gaussian elimination procedure, and I don't know of any methods that would be quicker (even with the zero row condition).

Comment: Use the following result:

Let $E_{ij}$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$ and whose all other entries are all $0.$ Then $AE_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $j^{th}$ column equals the $i^{th}$ column of $A$ and all other columns are zero, in combination with $\sum_{i=1}^{k}A(B_i)=A\big(\sum_{i=1}^{k}B_i \big),$ where $k \in \mathbb{N},$ for any $n\times n$ matrices $A,B_i's.$

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is equal $n-1$  whcih means the first 4n-1$ rows are linearly independent, there is a unique (up to a constant multiple) nonzero vector $v$ such that $v\in \ker A.$ Then all columns of $B$ should be multiples of $v.$ If the rank is lower than $n-1$ there are more possibilities as $\dim\ker A>1.$ Nontheless every column of $B$ should belong to $\ker A.$